# sequence of tenses issue (called)

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, backshifting

I am wondering Which one is correct "I had a traditional Filipino dish that is called tinolang manok." or "I had a traditional Filipino dish that was called tinolang manok."

Are both sentences correct?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct in both tenses.

The second one could carry a slightly different meaning in context, for example, if the dishes name was changed later on:

> I had a traditional Filipino dish that was called tinolang manok, but now it is called [...]

The focus of this sentence changed from the fact you had the dish to the change in the dishes name.

Comment: It depends on whether you think the name is a permanent thing or likely to change. Restaurants often change the name of their dishes, but if it's a classic like pad thai then you can assume it's still called that, and it's better to use the present tense.